# Why does $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{x_1,...,x_n\}$ have the same fundamental group as wedge sum of n circles?

Tags: algebraic-topology

As the title says, I don't know why the statement is true.
What I thought was, get non-overlapping circles $C_1, \cdots, C_n$ around $x_1, \cdots x_n$ (a bunch of $S^1$'s), and I understand that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{x_1, \cdots, x_n\}$ deformation retracts to $\{C_i\}_i$, where a few pairs of two circles are kissing each other. (Think about $\mathbb{R}^2$ deformation retracts to OOOOOOOO, circles drawn in a straight line.)

However, I don't understand why this can be viewed as a wedge sum; there's no reason that each $C_i$ has a base point $y_i$ that $\{y_1, \cdots, y_n\}$ are identified together. Can someone please clarify this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've concluded that it deformation retracts onto a set of circles joining together, then it's pretty close! Consider a path (arc) joining each intersection which is the composite of $(n-2)$ semicircles so it is homeomorphic to $[0,1]\simeq\{*\}$ (i.e. contractible) hence contract this curved line will identify all intersecting points together which gives you a wedge sum.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks for your comments. What if the path formed by arc forms a loop? Then, it cannot be contracted to a point.

Comment: On a second thought, I can construct a path while avoiding a loop. This set of circles is equivalent to a connected graph of $n$ vertices (each circle is a vertex and draw an edge if two circles are adjacent), and I can find a maximal spanning tree. A path equivalent to this spanning tree does not contain a loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be your union of circles $C_i$.  Let $Y\subset X$ be the union of the lower halves of the $C_i$: $\cup\cup\cup\cdots\cup$.  Thus $Y$ is homeomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$.  Now define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ by saying that $a\sim b$ if and only if $a,b\in Y$.  Then $X/\!\!\sim$ is the wedge of $n$ circles, so you just need to prove that the quotient map $X\to X/\!\!\sim$ is a homotopy equivalence.