# $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_k\} \simeq \bigvee_{j=1}^k S^{n-1}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is it true that by removing $k$ points from a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, we get a space homotopy equivalent to the wedge of $k$ $(n-1)$-spheres? More explicitly, $$\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_k\} \simeq \bigvee_{j=1}^k S^{n-1}.$$

I know that the case $k=1$ is true, and its fairly simple to prove by showing that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ deformation retracts to $S^{n-1}$ via the homotopy $F\colon\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}\times I \rightarrow\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$, given by $$F(x,t) = \frac{x}{1+t(\|x\|-1)},$$ thus showing that $$\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x_1\}\simeq S^{n-1}.$$

My question is whether there is a nice proof for the general case. I thought of using induction, but was unsuccessful, any ideas?

**Edit:** Another idea I had, I don't know if it is really useful or not, is that we could show that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}\vee \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\} \simeq \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{x_1,x_2\} $, and this would obviously generalize to $k=3,4,\dots$

Comment: If all the points were in a line, can you see how to deformation retract that space onto a 'chain' of spheres? then one just needs to contract a line connecting all the various wedge points to get a true wedge

Comment: This was discussed many times at MSE.

Comment: @DanRust are saying to explicitly define a deformation retraction? For example, let us suppose the $k$ points are on the first axis of $\mathbb{R^n}$, that is, $x_1 = (0,\dots,0)$, $x_2=(2,0,\dots,0)$,$\dots$, $x_k=(2k,0,\dots,0)$, then we could consider (n-1)-spheres of radii 1 centered on those points, I don't see a really easy way to write a deformation retraction, is there a way?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739597/why-does-mathbbr2-setminus-x-1-x-n-have-the-same-fundamental-grou?rq=1) helps?

Comment: You almost never want to explicitly write down a homotopy equivalence. This is one of those cases where it might technically be possible with a hell of a lot of work, but it would be pointless to do so.

Comment: @MoisheKohan ... and answered at least once by you ... See my close vote.